# Can't migrate Cassandra using joplin

Tags: cassandra, clojure, migration

I am trying to use [joplin](https://github.com/juxt/joplin) to run migrations for my Cassandra database.
However, when I run `lein migrate dev` I get the following exception:

```
Migrating #joplin.cassandra.database.CassandraDatabase{:hosts [127.0.0.1:9042], :keyspace test} 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy, compiling:(clojurewerkz/cassaforte/policies.clj:38:3)
```

I think the issue may lie in my migration but I am not sure what I've done wrong.

project.clj

```
(defproject app "0.1.0"
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
             [clojurewerkz/cassaforte "3.0.0-alpha1"]

             [joplin.core "0.3.10"]
             [joplin.cassandra "0.3.10"]

             [cc.qbits/alia "4.2.3"]
             [cc.qbits/hayt "4.0.2"]
             ]

:main app.cli.core

:source-paths ["src"]

:resource-paths ["resources"]

:test-paths ["test"]

:profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}}

:aliases {"migrate" ["run" "-m" "joplin.alias/migrate" "config.edn"]
        "seed" ["run" "-m" "joplin.alias/seed" "config.edn"]
        "rollback" ["run" "-m" "joplin.alias/rollback" "config.edn"]
        "reset" ["run" "-m" "joplin.alias/reset" "config.edn"]
        "pending" ["run" "-m" "joplin.alias/pending" "config.edn"]
        "create" ["run" "-m" "joplin.alias/create" "config.edn"]}
)
```

config.edn

```
{:migrators    {:cass-mig "resources/migrators"}
:seeds        {:cass-seed "seeds.cass/run"}
:databases    {:cass-dev {:type :cass, :hosts ["127.0.0.1:9042"], 
:keyspace "test"}}
:environments {:dev [{:db :cass-dev, :migrator :cass-mig, :seed :cass-seed}]}}
```

migrators

```
(ns migrators.20180717174605-test
  (:use [joplin.cassandra.database])
  (:require [clojurewerkz.cassaforte.client :as client]
[clojurewerkz.cassaforte.cql :refer :all]))

(defn up [db]
  (let [conn (client/connect (:hosts db))]
    (create-keyspace conn "test")))

(defn down [db]
  (let [conn (client/connect (:hosts db))]
    (drop-keyspace conn "test")))
```

Comment: can you check your classpath? is the datastax java driver included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alia & hayt instead of cassaforte for joplin 0.3.9+ see change doc [here](https://github.com/juxt/joplin/blob/9a16a8b4b35a2d1fef0d3c6901442ee07b0f90ef/CHANGES.md#039).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cc.qbits/alia` depends on the Cassandra Java driver 3.5.0, while the `cassaforte` with version 3.0.0-alpha1 depends on the older version - 2.1.6. It looks like that the `alia`'s dependency shadows the `cassaforte`s, and can't find the constructor for DCAware policy (in drivers 3.x, the builders are used instead of direct constructors).

You may install cassaforte from the repository - it was made to work with 3.x drivers.